# Memory Protection attributes

Tags: operating-system

A typical process consists of 4 memory regions text, data, heap and stack. What protection attributes does each of them have ?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This varies between operating systems, so no generally valid answer is possible, but typically it looks like this:

- text - read-execute
- data - read
- heap - read-write
- stack - read-write

Older operating systems might have text and data writable (some hardware does not allow to distinguish between read and read-execute either). Also, some operating systems will let you change this at will, and others will not (or will have some restrictions, such as not letting you set something to "execute" that was "write" before).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Damon. Could you tell me these attributes for  Linux/Unix OS ? Please let me know if there is a command in unix to verify these attributes.

Comment: The allowable values for Linux are listed e.g. under [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), which allows setting these (presuming proper rights). I've never needed to query protections, not sure if there is an easy way at all. Reading `/proc/[pid]/mem/maps` would be a good starting point. In my opinion, it's a bit pointless to query protection, because it's something one normally knows implicitly (and if you don't know, it means you didn't create the mapping, so you shouldn't tamper).